# malloc: get information from memory

Tags: c, caching, malloc

I am currently doing a project to simulate loading and storing info like a computer Cache.

I used malloc to load a struct into memory but I don't know how to retrieve that information again. 
For any line, I need to be able to call up a particular line in the cache and see if it causes a "hit or a miss" like a cache would.

```
struct cache {int s; int E; int b;}; //my struct

//creating a similated cache in memory.
struct cache** c1 = (struct cache**) malloc( pow(2,ssize) * Esize * sizeof(struct cache));`
```

Comment: This is totally unclear what you are trying to do and what you are asking about.

Comment: And a standard comment about integer power of `2` - do not use `pow`! Use bit-shifting.

Comment: Did I miss something or there is an actual question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically when you do

```
struct cache** c1 = (struct cache**) malloc( pow(2,ssize) * Esize * sizeof(struct cache)).
```

That is a pointer to pointer of struct cache. It is similar to an array of pointer to struct cache but it is not in your stack memory but in your heap memory. Nonetheless, you did it wrong. Each index of your struct cache ** suppose to be equal to the size of the pointer of struct cache. The code below probably explain everything.

After get space for struct cache **, each of its index you suppose to assign it with a pointer to struct * cache or malloc a pointer to struct cache with the size equal to the size struct cache. The code below, I created 10 index using malloc. So 0 - 9.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct cache {int s; int E; int b;}; //my struct

//creating a similated cache in memory.
int main(){
    // Each index equal the size of a pointer to struct cache and there is 10 index
    struct cache** c1 = (struct cache**) malloc( sizeof( struct cache* ) * 10 );

    // Each index is a pointer to struct cache with the malloc size it pointing
    // to equal to struct cache
    c1[0] = (struct cache*) malloc( sizeof(struct cache) );

    // Any later index would have to use malloc or assign a pointer to c1

    c1[0]->s = 1;
    c1[0]->E = 2;
    c1[0]->b = 3;

    printf("%d %d %d", c1[0]->s,
                       c1[0]->E,
                       c1[0]->b );
    return 0;

}
```